# ReflectionTypeLoadException with MonoTouch 4.0

Tags: ios, mono, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I updated MonoTouch to the brand new release 4.0 (no eval) yesterday. So I did with MonoDevelop (20509002), the Mono Framework (2.10.1), Xcode (3.2.6) and the iOS SDK (4.3).

So I thought I'd be ready to dive into my app again but after I ran the debug mode, I got a **ReflectionTypeLoadException** concerning a DLL I share with another computer (and yes, it's a DLL I built using Visual Studio 2010 on Windows).

New projects can still be debugged so it seemed to be my problem at all. Stripping off my project, I came to a point where the Exception came back to the Mono assemblies if the Linker was set to "Link SDK assemblies only" or "Link all assemblies";

**Linker: "Dont Link"**
1 error with my DLL

**Linker: "Link SDK assemblies only" or "Link all assemblies"**
220 erros with the mono DLLs (see attached img)

[Screenshot: Exception Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNvRk.png)

Now, if anyone has an idea how I could get back on track, please let me know. I can't wait to resume coding with MonoTouch!

Best regards,
Waescher

Comment: You're trying to use a DLL built on Windows?  That won't work.  You need to build it using MT.

Comment: It used to work like a charm until I made this update. Even if not - the 220 errors still occur without my assembly (with linker set to "sdk" or "all")

Comment: It worked by chance/accident.   We do not have plans on fixing that.

Comment: It's a very simple assembly containing some shared classes and interfaces. But the point was not the assembly itself but the errors with the Mono-Assemblies shown in the screenshot.

Comment: Seems that my assembly works in the simulator only. It can't be deployed to the device. No prob, I'll change that, thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay now, I just downgraded from MonoTouch 4.0 to 3.2.6. Now everything works just fine again. I had no other option, I'm afraid.

It's a pity that I can't use MT4 by now. Maybe the next update solves this issue.